# How to store Shapes in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, select, insert, geometry

I want to create a database using mongoDb and I am new to this area. And also want to Insert and select data to store shapes like circle, triangle, etc. I want to know how to do it.

Comment: Shapes in what format? Are you trying to store images, x-y coordinates, SVG data...?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to storing shapes for geospatial queries, you can use the new support for `GeoJSON` objects in MongoDB 2.4 to store and query Point, LineString, and Polygon objects.

For more information see:

- MongoDB 2.4 manual: [Geospatial Indexes and Queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) and [Geospatial Query Compatibility Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geospatial-queries/)
- The [GeoJSON 1.0 spec](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)